# block ads in iframe without sandbox

Tags: iframe, ads, block, sandbox

so I'm using I-frame to play video on my site, and to block ads I was using sandbox attribute to block ads in the embedded I-frame. but when I sandbox it disables the video and shows " Sandbox is not allowed ". so I want to ask if there's any way to block ads without using sandbox. Any java-script or anything?

Comment: Hi Saqib did you found any solution for this issue